# ALTIUM Setting all parts of a schematic to pcb library "Any"

Tags: altium

I have a schematic with different part in i. I have imported this schematic from another design and the parts are linked to a library I don't have access directly.

I need to set up all the parts in the schematics to be setted with their pcb library to point to any library. I can edit manually the pcb library where the part should point to any after what it found out the proper library automatically. However I would like to apply this to every part of my schematic.

I have tried to use the SCH inspector and change the Library parameters to Any but its seems it doesnt work.

Does anybody got idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools-> Footprint manager...

Select all components, and change PCB library to "ANY".